# How do I make new drop down boxes appear when another one has been filled in first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm building a graphic representation of a custom candle being made.

Right now, the idea is that the customer selects scents from a drop down box, in order. When they fill in one drop down box, the next one appears, up to five. My trouble is that I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it most efficiently.

```
    <div class="mainbody">
<div>
<span class="subtitle">Build Candles</span>
</div>
<div class="candle">
    <div class="candle_top">
    </div>
    <div class="candle_fifth">
    FIFTH
    </div>
    <div class="candle_fourth">
    FOURTH
    </div>
    <div class="candle_third">
    THIRD
    </div>
    <div class="candle_second">
    SECOND
    </div>
    <div class="candle_first">
    FIRST
    </div>
    <div class="candle_bottom">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="design">
<?php
$db_server="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_pword="";
$db_database="candles";

mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_pword);
if (strlen(mysql_error())>0) 
    {$PSUBMIT=5;
    $SQL['error']=mysql_error();
    $db_server="* Invalid * ";
    }
else mysql_select_db($db_database);
?>
<form method="get">
First:  <select name="first">
        <option></option>
        <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo '<option>'.$row[1].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select><br />

Second: <select name="second">
        <option></option>
        <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo '<option>'.$row[1].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select><br />

Third: <select name="third">
        <option></option>
        <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo '<option>'.$row[1].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select><br />

Fourth: <select name="fourth">
        <option></option>
        <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo '<option>'.$row[1].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select><br />

Fifth: <select name="fifth">
        <option></option>
        <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo '<option>'.$row[1].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Preview" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

I was thinking jQuery append, but I don't know how I would go about checking to see if First  is filled. Then if First and Second are filled to allow Third to be appended.

Comment: Ordinarily I'd have all elements already in the DOM, but hidden. Then just slideDown or fadeIn as needed using onChange. Should really show HTML for jQuery questions, and not all that PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val()!='') $(this).next('select:first').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XMx4Q

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $(this).next('select').fadeIn();
});
```